# change zPosition of tiles

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sktilemapnode, zposition

I want to change the zPosition of some tiles in my tile map. I use the following function to achieve this:

```
 static func setZPosition(to tileMap: SKTileMapNode, and tileInfo: String){

    let tileSize = tileMap.tileSize
    let halfWidth = CGFloat(tileMap.numberOfColumns) / 2 * tileSize.width
    let halfHeight = CGFloat(tileMap.numberOfRows) / 2 * tileSize.height

    for column in 0..<tileMap.numberOfColumns{
        for row in 0..<tileMap.numberOfRows{
            let tileDefinition = tileMap.tileDefinition(atColumn: column, row: row)
            let isCorrectTile = tileDefinition?.userData?[tileInfo] as? Bool
            if isCorrectTile ?? false{
                let x = CGFloat(column) * tileSize.width - halfWidth
                let y = CGFloat(row) * tileSize.height - halfHeight
                let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tileSize.width, height: tileSize.height)
                let tileNode = SKShapeNode(rect: rect)
                tileNode.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
                tileNode.zPosition = 100
                tileMap.addChild(tileNode)
                print(tileNode.zPosition)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I use this function, the print statetement shows me 5 times "100". This is correct because I want to change the zPosition of 5 tiles with the userData name "Z", which I use as the tileInfo parameter. The player sprite has a ZPosition of 10. But if I walk now with the player over a tile with zPosition 100, the player is still above the Tile. I want him to be behind the tile. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not changing a zPosition, you are creating new tiles and placing them on the tile map,  is this intended?

Comment: I just went through Apple Docs,  I do not think you can change the zPosition of tiles,  I see nothing in their tile definition that does this.  So it looks like you are using SKShapeNode to place a new tile over the original tile, but you never specify the color for SKShapeNode, so it is most likely transparent

Comment: oh yes thanks, now I see why this can't work.. then I have to use SpriteNodes instead of tiles.. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the definition that allows for zPosition change (Which would make sense since the idea is to draw the tiles as fast as possible)

I would recommend having another tile set overlay it, or have individual sprites that pop out.

Comment: I used a separate tile map as an overlay, thanks for the help!